# MAGENTO2: Discount Bug - Magento2 (2.3.3)

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.3.3

I have a fixed discount rule configured as follows:

[image: Promotion Configuration - spend $100 or more to get $100 off]

Now the way I expected this to work is if you have >= $100 in your basket you can use the voucher COACH100. The actual outcome is the code will only apply if the cost of the basket is still going to be >= $100, is that the correct behaviour?

If it is correct behaviour, is it possible to acheive the outcome I require?

Comment: If this isn't a bug can someone just confirm that please as we used to be able to run promotions like this on Magento 1.9 without issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...

In this scenario - because the promotion rule is set to subtotal (ex tax) >= $100 it means that the subtotal calculated after the promotion is taken off and before the tax is added.

Well if you want them to spend atleast $100 and give them $100 off you can't calculate that ex tax because the $100 will be taken off and not leave you with enough to pass the rule to get the discount so it gets taken off again.

Setting it to just the subtotal will work.